# Disabling System.Net.Trace logging from VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2013, .net-trace

This is a strange question...

A while ago I contacted Azure support to debug some issues surrounding web app deployment from visual studio 2013. In order to diagnose this issue he screen shared with me and walked me through setting up network traces to be logged to a temporary folder in My Documents, which I could then send to him.

At the time I was kind of mindlessly going through the tasks, and we never disabled the system.net.trace logging.

Fastforward about 6/7 months and my C drive is at capacity, which is rather ridiculous. I track down the location of this memory hogging system.net.trace.log file and it's size is in the region of 20+GB....and obviously can't even be opened with any text editor I have.

I have deleted the file but it is now obviously growing again.

I can't for the life of me remember what it was we did/edited in order to implement this system.net.trace.log. I know I added a chunk of text to a config file provided by the engineer. So my question(s) are:

- Does anybody have any clue how this would standardly be implemented (googling has taught me there are many varied situations in which people set this type of thing up, mine was to diagnose a web publish issue).
- If not is there any way of finding out the config file which we changed, it must sit behind Visual Studio somewhere but that folder tree is like a labyrinth.

I could just have a batch file dispose of the log on startup to prevent further issues like with memory, but this is bugging me now. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

This was probably turned on at the machine.config level (although I believe it's possible at the web.config level, too -- but I assume you've already looked there).

The `machine.config` file is located in the path of the .NET Framework version which you are targeting ... something like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` -- although you might need to look in a different framework version depending on your installation and target.

Just set all the values under `<switches>` to `Off`.

```
<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Off"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Off"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Off"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Off"/>
  <add name="System.Net.WebSockets" value="Off"/>
</switches>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have located the Machine.config file but it has no switches node in it. I have searched the whole Windows folder, searching the file contents, for "Switches", "trace", "System.net.trace" and the file location of the log file it is writing to. I haven't found any config files in these searches. I'm pretty confused! @Dusty

Comment: Okay, sorry this didn't get it fixed. For clarity, you did also check your app's web.config file, right?

Comment: Yeah I did. Thanks for the help, I got excited as this file I can't find is driving me nuts, shame!